# Best performance for searching on landing page set criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I have two SQL2005 tables:

- Table 1: LandingPages
- Table 2: Products

The **LandingPages** table manages the heading, description and other details that are displayed on each of about 200 targetted landing pages. Each record also has a set of default Criteria fields that specify what products should be shown on each individual landing page.

So, a landing page about widgets with red tops and blue bottoms would have a record thus:

- LPID: 1
- Title: Widgets with Red Tops and Blue Bottoms
- Product Category: Widget
- Top: Red
- Bottom: Blue

Each landing page record has a unique ID, called **LPID**.

I want a stored procedure that takes the LPID, reads the criteria and then returns a recordset of matching products.

What is the best way to achieve this for performance?

I have tried reading the various criteria into lots of variables, then doing a select using the variables in the WHERE of the SELECT.

I am trying to see if a CTE can be used / is better than my current method, but I'm not sure I can use the CTE within the WHERE of my SELECT.

--
*Extra note: certain options can be changed by the user, such as maximum price and sorting.*

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Sure we can help. That isn't a problem. However, you need to provide details so we are able to help. Take a look at this link for a great starting point. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I was really looking for an overview of best practice for this particular problem to point me in the right direction, rather than a code-level example.

Comment: But your question is so incredibly vague we can't possibly give you an overview. You asked if there is a better way than your current method, what is your current method? You seem to want some help but you have forgotten to ask a complete question.